# Insert value of ACF into other ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have field(Wysiwyg Editor) in my WP site and in this content present link. I need to paste value for this link with value from other ACF field.

[image: 1]

So i need to paste value of other field on place where "https://some-url.com" is located.

I've tried to paste some php code in field in WP but nothing happened

Comment: This isn't making a lot of sense, can you explain when you need this to happen? When you save the page after editing? Or on the front end for user?

Comment: it needs to be inserted new value when second field is changed. Cause on one field used on other page and i needs to have link from it in other filed